# How To Compile Cross Referenced Files?

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, makefile

I have six files and they all referencr to some other file, how to compile them under linux? how to write the make file?

1. FileA.h
   FileA.cpp
   define the main() and f(), it also references to b()
2. FileB.h.
   FileB.cpp
   define the b(), and reference to c()
3. FileC.h
   FileC.cpp
   define the c() and reference to f()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple Makefile can be used as a start:

```
CXXFLAGS=-I.

all: FileA.o FileB.o FileC.o
    $(CXX) -o app $^

FileA.o: FileA.cpp FileA.h
FileB.o: FileB.cpp FileB.h
FileC.o: FileC.cpp FileC.h

clean:
    rm app -f *.o
```

Test (GNU Make 3.81):

```
$ make
g++ -I.   -c -o FileA.o FileA.cpp
g++ -I.   -c -o FileB.o FileB.cpp
g++ -I.   -c -o FileC.o FileC.cpp
g++ -o app FileA.o FileB.o FileC.o
```

---

Here is a more general version：

```
CPPFLAGS=-I.

SRCS=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJS=$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRCS))
TGT=app

$(TGT): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^

%.o : %.cpp %.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f $(TGT) $(OBJS)
```

Test (GNU Make 3.81):

```
$ make
g++ -c -I.  -o FileA.o FileA.cpp
g++ -c -I.  -o FileB.o FileB.cpp
g++ -c -I.  -o FileC.o FileC.cpp
g++ -o app FileA.o FileB.o FileC.o
$ touch FileB.h
$ make
g++ -c -I.  -o FileB.o FileB.cpp
g++ -o app FileA.o FileB.o FileC.o
$ make clean
rm -f app FileA.o FileB.o FileC.o
```

Answer (score 0):

For this compilation you need simple makefile like

```
XX = g++
CFLAGS = -g
INC := -I./include

TGT = ./test

%.o:%.cpp
    $(XX) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c $< -o $@

SOURCES = $(wildcard *.c *.cpp)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SOURCES)))

$(TGT) : $(OBJS)
    $(XX) $(OBJS) $(INC) -o $(TGT) 
    chmod 777 $(TGT)
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~
```